# What does The input is reflected inside a tag parameter between double quotes mean?

Tags: xss, sql-injection

A recent scan of [Acunetix](https://www.acunetix.com/) has shown some [vulnerability](https://www.trojanmart.com/verif.php?afficher_forgot_password=Oui%22sTYLe=%27acu:Expre/**/SSion(Afih(9717))%27bad=%22&lang_abbreviation=en&membre=) on one of my pages. I tried reproducing it but i can not find any vulnerability. The so called vulnerably is titled **The input is reflected inside a tag parameter between double quotes mean**.

The scan gives me the following result for my [page](https://www.trojanmart.com/verif.php?afficher_forgot_password=Oui%22sTYLe=%27acu:Expre/**/SSion(Afih(9717))%27bad=%22&lang_abbreviation=en&membre=).

```
verif.php
Details URL encoded GET input afficher_forgot_password was set to **Oui"sTYLe='acu:Expre/**/SSion(Afih(9717))'bad="**
The input is reflected inside a tag parameter between double quotes.

Request headersGET /verif.php?afficher_forgot_password=Oui"sTYLe='acu:Expre/**/SSion(Afih(9717))'bad="&lang_abbreviation=en&membre= HTTP/1.1
 Connection: keep-aliveCookie: PHPSESSID=feef28e9052ce51f6701e34749ca30ac;lang_abbreviation=enAccept: */*Accept-Encoding: gzip, User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, likeGecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36
```

Here is a [direct link](https://www.trojanmart.com/verif.php?afficher_forgot_password=Oui%22sTYLe=%27acu:Expre/**/SSion(Afih(9717))%27bad=%22&lang_abbreviation=en&membre=) that reproduces the so called vulnerability but I do not see any vulnerability on the page.  what does The input is reflected inside a tag parameter between double quotes mean ?

Comment: Cross posted https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/214726/what-does-the-input-is-reflected-inside-a-tag-parameter-between-double-quotes-me

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest that it's because you have a double(s) quote in your parameter value.

> Oui"sTYLe='acu:Expre/**/SSion(Afih(9717))'bad="

If this is being inserted into a DB and is being parameterized correctly, it shouldn't be a problem.

However, this should be properly URL encoded to prevent this kind of potential issue. Since your value could apparently/possibly could also include an ampersand, it could throw off or interrupt the other parameters, or simply inject it's own parameter with the knowledge your code will accept it.

If you ***really*** need it in this format for your code to work, you can always decode it server side. You can also look at `POST`ing this with the parameter in the body of the request, rather than the URL. You'll still likely want to URL encode it, but it'll likely be less of a problem for automated scanning tools.

Comment: URL encoding is for encoding data sent in HTTP GET or POST parameters, not for rendering data on a page. The poster doesn't need this "format" to work, it was only something that came up in a vulnerability scan, so there is no need to try to decode this or anything.

Comment: @multithr3at3d, I added that in case they were doing something like using it for creating HTML tags, where they are using it as a string. This isn't a good example of passing an HTML tag as a string, but others might do it. I'm not even saying it's a good idea to pass HTML tags as string, I'm just giving options for what can be possible.